# I am trying to print a statement that will show any number that is great than 5

Tags: python

I am trying to print any number that is great than n, which is 5 in this case. It is only printing 6 and 7. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. This is my code. I am looping through the array and testing if i is greater then n (5)

```
list = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
n = 5
filter_list (list, n)

def filter_list (list, n):
` `for i in range(len(list)):
` `if list[i] > n:
` `print (list[i])
```

the outcome is `only 6, 7.` Its not `6, 7, 8, 9` which is what I would like it

It doesnt print the desired outcome

Comment: this code works well for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working if you give indent before if statement

```
list = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
n = 5

def filter_list (list, n):
    for i in range(len(list)):
        if list[i] > n:
            print (list[i])

filter_list (list, n)
```

Or you can try this code :

```
list1 = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
n = 5

for i in list1 :
    if i > n:
        print(I)
```

Hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

For me your code working fine just fix the indent. Just adding `end ''` at print to print on same line.

```
list = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
n = 5


def filter_list (list, n):
    for i in range(len(list)):
        if list[i] > n:
            print (list[i],end =' ')
        
filter_list (list, n)
```

Gives #

```
6 7 8 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is completely fine, if you fix your intent.

```
list = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
n = 5


def filter_list (list, n):
    for i in range(len(list)):
        if list[i] > n:
            print (list[i],end =' ')

print(filter_list (list, n))
```

Output: `6 7 8 9`

And you don’t need to call a function. If we use list compression we can increase speed and code readability ‍

```
list = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

n = 5

print(list(i for i in List if i > n))
```